# too many ssh-agent process per user on several servers

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, ssh-agent, background-process

Several users seem to have problems with the usage of ssh-agent in their login environment.  sri for instance has 1295 of them running on login02. And many other users are having same issue.

I am seeing the same problem on other machines, and with other people also.

```
sri 32586  0.0  0.0  11144     0 ?        Ss    2019   0:00 ssh-agent
sri 32598  0.0  0.0  11144  1304 ?        Ss   Jan13   0:03 ssh-agent
sri 32608  0.0  0.0  11148     0 ?        Ss    2019   0:00 ssh-agent
sri 32610  0.0  0.0  11152     0 ?        Ss   Jan22   0:00 ssh-agent
sri 32640  0.0  0.0  11148     0 ?        Ss    2019   0:00 ssh-agent
sri 32643  0.0  0.0  11148     0 ?        Ss    2019   0:00 ssh-agent
sri 32656  0.0  0.0  11144     0 ?        Ss    2019   0:00 ssh-agent
sri 32711  0.0  0.0  11152     0 ?        Ss    2019   0:00 ssh-agent
sri 32715  0.0  0.0  11144     0 ?        Ss    2019   0:00 ssh-agent
sri 32755  0.0  0.0  11152     0 ?        Ss    2019   0:00 ssh-agent
sri 32765  0.0  0.0  11148     0 ?        Ss    2019   0:00 ssh-agent
root@login02:~$ ps -aux | grep ssh-agent | grep sri | wc -l
1295
root@login02:~$ ps -aux | grep ssh-agent  | wc -l
1509
root@login02:~$
```

Please guide me how to fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: May be there some active `tmux` sessions? Because there is a lot agents running from last year.

Comment: What distribution are you using? **systemd** can automatically spawn an ssh-agent, when the user logs in and terminate it, when the last user session exits.

Comment: VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
4.4.0-109-generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user is probably spawning those **ssh-agent**'s in his shell init scripts (`.profile`, `.bashrc` or similar), but forgot to kill the agent in the logout scripts. Maybe even the global shell init scripts spawn **ssh-agent**'s.

A way to stop this proceeding is to offer your users a system-wide way to administer **ssh-agent**'s.

The easiest way to control the number of **ssh-agent** instances is to use **systemd** together with [pam_systemd](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/pam_systemd.8.html). This will spawn a [SystemD User Manager](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/user@.service.html) for each logged in user and terminate whenever the last user session exits. Moreover it allows to define user services, whose lifetime is independent from user sessions.

Ubuntu 16.04 [does not provide](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/openssh-client/filelist) `.service` files for **ssh-agent** (newer versions do), but you can create one yourself by adding a file `/etc/systemd/user/ssh-agent.service` with content:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenSSH Agent
Documentation=man:ssh-agent(1)
Before=default.target
Wants=dbus.socket
After=dbus.socket

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a %t/ssh-agent
```

and a symlink of the file in the `/etc/systemd/user/default.target.wants` directory:

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/user/default.target.wants
ln -s ../ssh-agent.service /etc/systemd/user/default.target.wants
```

followed by a `systemctl daemon-reload`. You'll need also to add to `/etc/bash.bashrc` the following line:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent
```

After this configuration step:

- the first time a user connects to the system, an **ssh-agent** will be spawned. You can check its status with:

  ```
  systemctl --user status ssh-agent.service
  ```
- every ssh client in every session will have access to the **same** ssh-agent,
- when the last user session terminates, so does the ssh-agent.